# on RHES 7.7, using tool ora2pg, importing data from oracle fails with error Can't locate DBD/Pg.pm in @INC

Tags: postgresql, perl, ora2pg

OS Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7

Tool: ora2pg Ora2Pg v23.2

Action: Migrate **data** from Oracle 12 schema tables to a flat file using ora2pg as below

```
ora2pg -c config/ora2pg.conf -t COPY --pg_dsn "dbi:Pg:dbname=scratchpad;host=<HOST>;port=5432" > data/data.csv
```

fails with the following message

```
 ora2pg -c config/ora2pg.conf -t COPY --pg_dsn "dbi:Pg:dbname=scratchpad;host=<HOST>;port=5432" > data/data.csv
[========================>] 54/54 tables (100.0%) end of scanning.
install_driver(Pg) failed: Can't locate DBD/Pg.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at (eval 20) line 3.
Perhaps the DBD::Pg perl module hasn't been fully installed,
or perhaps the capitalisation of 'Pg' isn't right.
Available drivers: DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, Mem, Oracle, Proxy, SQLite, Sponge.
```

A search in Google suggested installing perl-DBD-Pg package (see https://github.com/mikaku/Monitorix/issues/314). First this is what is installed

```
yum list installed | grep "^perl-DB[ID]"
perl-DBD-SQLite.x86_64                1.39-3.el7             @rhel-7-server-rpms
perl-DBI.x86_64                       1.627-4.el7            @rhel-7-server-rpms
```

Tried to install package

```
yum install perl-DBD-Pg
```

get error

```
No package perl-DBD-Pg available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Tried to find work arounds but no luck so fare.

Appreciate any advice. FYI, the schema export from Oracle with ora2pg works fine.

Comment: Should work.  There seems to be something wrong with your repo or how your yum is set up.  This is not about programming, or directly about postgresql or perl.

Comment: Thanks jjanes

This is the error getting with yum install perl-DBD-Pg
 From       : https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc
Is this ok [y/N]: y
virtualbox/7Server/x86_64/signature                                                                                                                             | 2.9 kB  00:00:06 !!!
http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/el/7Server/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for virtualbox
Trying other mirror.
No package perl-DBD-Pg available.

Comment: Thanks I sorted this out. There was a problem with subscription manager to redhat

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was an issue with subscription manager to redhat. Resolved